# find button that is within 3 divs selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to find the text of a button. here is the html layout.

```
<div id="fulfillment-add-to-cart-button">
  <div class="fulfillment">
    <div>
     <div style="position:relative">
       <button class="btn ban-disabled"> Sold Out </button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='fulfillment-add-to-cart-button']/div/div/div/button[0]")
```

I keep returning a empty array. I've tried also finding the button with the button classname however that also returns an empty array.

Comment: maybe you should reduce `div` to `// and use `find_element_` without char `s` in word `element` and without `[0]` - `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='fulfillment-add-to-cart-button']//button")`

Comment: if page use JavaScript to add it then you may need `time.sleep(0.1)` and JavaScript will have time to add elements.

Comment: it would be much simpler if you would add minimal working code with real URL - and then we can test it and see problem.

Comment: do you have problem to get first `div`? maybe all this HTML is inside `<frame>` and you may need to `switch_to` this frame.

Comment: Is there an url we can work with?

Answer (score 0):

The button is a single element, correct?  So you would find by `element`, not `elements`.

Try this, to search for that specific text within that button

```
button_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='fulfillment-add-to-cart-button']//button")
print(button_elem.text)
```

If that doesn't work we may need to see more of the HTML that surrounds that section